# how to convert string to array using explode?

Tags: php, string

How to convert this string into array using php? thank you in advance here is string:

```
((-111.448843339275,56.8746856298617))
```

Comment: this is same string? which seperator you want to use

Comment: You should explain a little more. Which programming language you use?

Comment: What output you expect ?

Comment: @Mr.M look the tag. he is using php

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '((-111.448843339275,56.8746856298617))';
$str = str_replace ( array('((','))') , '', $str);
$array = explode(',',$str);
```

Comment: I don't know @Rakesh_Sharma. maybe common sense? 2 float type numbers separated with comma and wrapped inside double brackets. Simple as that.

Comment: if the answer is correct, mark it as an answer with green thick under voting buttons.